# select a data in a group which is the newest by linq

Tags: c#, linq

if I have a data like that:

```
UserId / Department / AddedOn
1 / IT / 2012.10.1
2 / IT / 2012.11.1
3 / Sale / 2012.10.2
4 / Sale / 2012.9.1
```

i wanna get the newest user who is the newest in their Department

```
var query  = _dbConetxt.DepartmentUsers.GroupBy(x=>x.Department)
.Select(x=>new{
x.Key, // this is Department
UserId = null // <--- this is my question, how to get this UserId by lastest AddedOn
});
```

Comment: var query  = dbConetxt.GroupBy(x=>x.Department)
.Select(x=>new{
x.Key, 
x.UserId 
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just order each group by date added descending, and select first user:

```
var query  = dbContext.Users
                 .GroupBy(u => u.Department)
                 .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u => u.AddedOn).First());
```

That will return most recently added user from each department (you even don't need to create anonymous type).